Clojure equivalent to the Perl "unpack" function
In Perl, unpack can be used to neatly split a string of fixed-length fields into its parts. What follows is an example of it being used to accomplish this:
# get a 5-byte string, skip 3, then grab 2 8-byte strings, then the rest
my ($leading, $s1, $s2, $trailing) = unpack("A5 x3 A8 A8 A*", $data);

Is there an equivalent to unpack in Clojure?

Seems to me this would be easy to implement.

I would also note that on the JVM, strings are not a mechanism to transmit binary data, as pack and unpack use them in Perl. Strings are UTF-16 encoded, and so there are binary strings they cannot represent. If you want a very simple string-only parser, then regexes are a reasonable choice, as Eugene recommends. If you need anything but A and x, you'll need to learn how to handle binary data.

Given how mature Clojure is, I was curious as to how it handled binary data packed in strings.  I wanted to see if there was something ready-made that I could use without rolling my own code.  I used the Perl unpack code to be a purely illustrative example of a ready-made, one step approach to handling binary data.  Thanks for the feedback.

No, and there's no the corresponding pack.
I'd use RegExes. Although I can't really tell how exact of an alternative that is since I don't know Perl and how it handles multibyte characters in strings.
;; If you prefer named groups.
(let [data "xxxxx___yyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz1234awerasdf"
      pattern #"(?<leading>.{5}).{3}(?<s1>.{8})(?<s2>.{8})(?<trailing>.*)"
      matcher (re-matcher pattern data)]
  (re-find matcher)
  (into {}
        (map (fn [[n idx]]
               [(keyword n) (.group matcher ^long idx)]))
        (.namedGroups matcher)))

;; If you prefer to rely on positions.
(let [data "xxxxx___yyyyyyyyzzzzzzzz1234awerasdf"
      pattern #"(.{5}).{3}(.{8})(.{8})(.*)"
      [_ leading s1 s2 trailing] (re-matches pattern data)]
  {:leading  leading
   :s1       s1
   :s2       s2
   :trailing trailing})

